# What is the difference between "progress in" and "progress toward"?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

Are these examples correct?

I made progress in losing weight.

I made progress toward a slimmer body.

Comment: You make "progress in" a field of endeavor.  You make "progress toward" a goal.

Answer (score 1):

Both prepositions can be used. The choice of the preposition depends on the following after the idiom 'make progress' either the object or the aim of the activity.
In the first case we use IN, in the second case we use  TOWARD(S).
See some examples from Oxford and Collins Dictionaries:
'She is making progress in maths'.
'The medical community continues to make progress in the fight against cancer'.
'We are making progress towards equal rights'.
'The two sides made little if any progress towards agreement'. 
One more example from Reverso.Context.net:
'Recently, working with Russia, Argentina, Hungary and South Africa, we have made significant progress toward that goal'.